# RewriteRule accepts numbers but not letters in tag

Tags: permalinks, tags, rewrite-rules, characters

### RewriteRule only works with numbers

I currently try to get the link

> example.com/subdir/StackExchange/

to act as a link with e.g. an additional website tag:

> example.com/subdir?website=StackExchange

---

I set up a RewriteRule in the .htaccess that looks as following:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)/$ subdir.php?website=$1 [L]
```

When I use numbers (`example.com/subdir/123/`), `echo $_GET["website"]` successfully echoes "123". As soon as I use alphabetical letters (`example.com/subdir/abc/`) it does **not** work.

How do I get this changed? Is this an issue with WordPress? I have set the permalink option in the WordPress Settings Dashboard to "Post name". I tried other methods, too, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave `.htaccess` alone. You can use WordPress [rewrite API](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) for this.

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    return add_rewrite_rule(
        'subdir/([^/]+)/?$', // ([^/]+) takes alphanumeric, while ([0-9]+) accepts digits
        'index.php?pagename=subdir&website=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});

add_filter('query_vars', function($v){ return array_merge(array('website'),$v); });
```

First make sure `subdir` is a valid page slug, in this example. After you save that code to your child theme's functions file or plugin, you can now use [`get_query_var('website')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) to get the `website` property rather than using `$_GET` global.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Samuel, thanks for your answer. I tried to use your code, but I still receive 404s when using alphanumerics, while numbers are still working. I removed the rule from .htaccess, so that can't be the reason why it still occurs. It is also a valid page slug. These Rules are also within the .htaccess:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NS]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NS]
`

Is one of them blocking it? For me, it does not seem like it.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: After adding the code, did you go to `Settings > Permalinks` and hit the saving button (to flush the rules)? Just restore your `.htaccess` with a fresh copy from [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/)

Comment: Flushing the rules did it finally! Thank you so much Samuel, you really ended my hours-long struggle! =)

Comment: You're very welcome. Have a good day!